# IntelliJ IDEA: "Indexed Maven Repositories" list - how to add remote maven repository in this list?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea, repository, indexed

I'm having trouble understanding how to get repositories in the "Indexed Maven Repositories" list of the IntelliJ IDEA.

In one my project I have two repos in this list: one local and one (main) remote (see attached screenshot below). And in other project (created using AppFuse template) I have only one (local) repo in list.

I'm tried to add the repos in pom.xml file and in settings.xml file, but the repos  did not appear in this "magic" list.

And this means:

1. I can't see artifactId and versions of artifacts in dropdownlist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>)
2. IDEA can't find the necessary artifacts (or his versions). It is looking only in my local repo

---

Version of IntelliJ IDEA: 11.0

Version of Maven: 2.2.1

[image: snapshot of settings]

Comment: I've just been looking at this and I think you havent tested the latest enterprise version properly. If you change the "User setting file:" to the name of a file that doesn't exist the system doesn't even show an error. If you change the settings file it is not pickd up. Not impressed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This list is updated automatically from the repositories specified in your pom files (or inherited from parent project's pom and *settings.xml*).

If you open a project that has some additional repositories specified, you'll see them in this list and will be able to update the indices.

Comment: yep! It's really works.. I found the problem in other place (some of artifacts has a wrong versions..)
Thank you, Anton! )

Comment: ...except for `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` which seems to be some kind of undocumented default

Answer (score 22):

You can manage these settings by editing your settings.xml file of the project

1. Open the Project file list (Ctrl-1)
2. Find your main parent pom.xml file
3. Right click on it Choose **Maven -> Open 'settings.xml'**

As you can see it is a local copy of settings.xml file for your project.
There is you can add/remove active repositories of the project.
Look at the [settings->repositories](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) manual for details.

Answer (score 8):

I had a related issue where I changed the repository in my settings.xml but the Indexed Maven Repositories list was still pointing to the old one.  In order to get the maven build to look at the new one I had to run mvn idea:idea on the project

Comment: Ahh, this has been killing me. Thank you tons!

Answer (score 1):

For the visitors futured, I solved this issue changing the version of jdk