# IntelliJ IDEA: “Indexed Maven Repositories” list - how to REMOVE a remote maven repository in this list?

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea, repository

I really wanted this to be a comment to the answer posted in the thread [IntelliJ IDEA: "Indexed Maven Repositories" list - how to add remote maven repository in this list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150535/intellij-idea-indexed-maven-repositories-list-how-to-add-remote-maven-repos) but my reputation does not allow for it. So please excuse this being posted as a new Question.

Is there any way to remove a repository from the "Indexed Maven Repositories" list? I moved projects and still see my old repositories in there, some of which have actually been taken offline.

I have tried re-importing my settings.xml file, restarting IntelliJ multiple times(invalidating the cache too), but cannot get those repositories to go away from this list.

Comment: What if you do `Open Project` and re-import root pom.xml?

Comment: That does not work too. Looks like intelliJ just caches it somewhere. I created a completed new project, but the indexed list still showed up. Anyway,  have since moved to Eclipse - so this question does not matter anymore.

Comment: Vic - Opening the project and re-importing the pom.xml does not do anything. This sees to be cached on the intelliJ side, and remains the same for all poms

Comment: I neither have the proxy repo which I am trying to delete in settings.xml nor in any of the pom.xml files. What can I do here?

Answer (score 3):

All my repositories got removed from this list, probably because I've moved the project to another directory on my device.
My solution was to delete the `jarRepositories.xml` file, which is located inside the `.idea` folder.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the "indexed maven repository" I wanted to remove wasn't defined in Maven's settings.xml, but was defined inside one of my many sub-project's pom.xml file. I had to delete the following section from a pom.xml file. After deleting that from the pom.xml file the "indexed maven repository" was removed from Maven's settings in IntelliJ

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>foo</id>
        <name>foo</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/maven/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: I neither have the proxy repo which I am trying to delete in settings.xml nor in any of the pom.xml files. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: Just delete the file ".idea" in your program's root file, and open the pom.xml as a new program, then you will find the "indexed maven repositories" is modified automatically.

Comment: I neither have the proxy repo which I am trying to delete in settings.xml nor in any of the pom.xml files. What can I do here?