# How to add repository/repositories to "Indexed Maven Repositories" in IntelliJ IDEA 13?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-13

How to add repository/repositories to "Indexed Maven Repositories" in IntelliJ IDEA 13?
[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150535/intellij-idea-indexed-maven-repositories-list-how-to-add-remote-maven-repos

Comment: It isn't duplicated, I have been read this.

Comment: Do you read red text: "Nothing at here!" on screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple Maven project by IntelliJ IDEA:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Choose "Enable Auto-Import"
[image]
Then, add these to `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
        <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Come back to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S), "Indexed Maven Repositories" section updated:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Add this repisitory to settings.xml in maven:

```
<project> 
  <repositories> 
        <repository>
            <id>my-internal-site</id> 
            <url>http://myserver/repo</url> 
         </repository> 
     </repositories> 
 </project>
```

Comment: <project> tag should not be used in settings.xml, use it in pom's project instead. In settings.xml to set a repo you should put it inside <profile> tag https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html