# Clojure pedestal.io code is not resolved in IntelliJ

Tags: clojure, intellij-13, boot-clj, cursive, pedestal

I have a small application of Clojure and Pedestal that I grabbed from pedestal.io tutorial. It works fine in the terminal. When I open it in IntelliJ some "cannot be resolved" tips are appearing. And some code parts are getting a beige background.

[image]

I have Cursive plugin installed. The code is executed by `boot repl`. Is any way to resolve full code by IntelliJ? If so, which settings?

### Update

"Indexed Maven Repositories" field

[image]

Comment: AFAIK does Cursive only support the last three major releases (i can not look for the source, but i asked the author in IRC when i was using '14).

Comment: looks like even clojure.core symbols are not being resolved (see ns and defn in snippet) - I think your problem is more general than just pedestal symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your settings to make sure both Clojars and Maven repos are indexed:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Settings]

Navigate to:

```
File
-> Settings
   -> Build, Execution, Deployment 
      -> Build Tools
         -> Maven
            -> Repositories
```

And make sure it looks like the above picture.  If necessary, highlight both the Maven & Clojars repos and click "Update", then "OK" (you don't need to wait for it to finish as it is a background process).

---

**Also**, it is frequently helpful to do

```
File 
  -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

---

Then it will resolve correctly:

[image: How Cursive Should Look]

---

**Update #2**

OK, I see you have a `boot` project.  I have a `lein` project, and Cursive populated my list automatically (from `project.clj` I assume). Two ways forward:

1. Search the docs, SO, & Cursive mailing list for `boot` info. The Cursive author is very responsive to items [on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!forum/cursive):
2. If the above doesn't work, maybe convert it to a `lein` project just to make Cursive/IntelliJ happy.  You can still run it as a `boot` project from the command line (or however you normally use boot).

For more info, see also this question:   [IntelliJ IDEA: "Indexed Maven Repositories" list - how to add remote maven repository in this list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150535/intellij-idea-indexed-maven-repositories-list-how-to-add-remote-maven-repos)

and the reference:  http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

---

**Update #3:**

OK, just found this `boot` Cursive info, which looks good:   https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/For-Cursive-Users

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the "Indexed Maven Repositories" field, that you have shown in the first picture, is empty. I show it in a screenshot in an update to the question.