# maven doesn't find any artifacts any more (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

All of a sudden maven (in IntelliJ IDEA) doesn't find any artifacts any more. I used to be able to just click on the class and maven would automatically add the corresponding dependency to the pom file.

All of a sudden, maven doesn't find anything any more, see screenshot:

[image]

Under Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories, I updated the remote maven repository.

It didn't help.

How can I fix this?

---

UPDATE:
here's the address of the maven repository I use:
[image]

---

UPDATE 2:

1)
There is no settings.xml file in folder .m2 because I haven't changed the default location of my local maven repository.
2)
Under Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven, one sees this:
[image]

Comment: Check that you use the Maven Central with HTTPS. This is likely you are using the HTTP one, which is no longer available.

Comment: @NoDataFound Thank you for your comment ... it's https though, see the update to the post

Comment: Check if Intellij (preferences) is using the correct maven (version, settings). Also, check your settings.xml file in .m2 folder.

Comment: Have the indexes finished rebuilding?

Comment: @HediAyed: what do you mean by the correct maven? ... what would be an incorrect maven? As you can see from the screenshot in my post, my IntelliJ IDEA uses maven version 3.6.1. Is that ok?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ... thank you for your comment ... what do you mean by "Have the indexes finished rebuilding?" ... Maybe it's a stupid question but: which indexes do you mean? And why would they rebuild?

Comment: One of IntelliJ's forces is that it indexes _everything_ so that you can search in it and that it can use that information to give qualified assistance.  When you update the Maven remote repository it is my understanding that a redownload takes place and then indexes needs to be built anew before IntelliJ can assist you properly again.

Answer (score 1):

Try just using the embedded Maven without adding any repository URL, works for me

Comment: I cannot remove any repository, though

Comment: Try deleting the .idea folder (or save it on another place) and then reimport your project

Comment: I didn't import the project, I created a new project ... what's the point of removing the .idea folder?

Comment: it contains the intellij project settings, so if there's something wrong with it maybe recreating a new one may solve the issue

Comment: it didn't help ... I even created a whole new project from scratch but the problem persists

Comment: Check if this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150535/intellij-idea-indexed-maven-repositories-list-how-to-add-remote-maven-repos

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug: [IDEA-215618](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215618) that is planned to be fixed in 2020.1 IDE version update. As a workaround you could use *Search for artifact* tab.

Comment: thank you for your answer ... however, the bug you mention has already been fixed